# What are Natures? What do they do?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Every pokemon has something called nature. It can increase some stats and make pokemon better overall.

What are the natures and what do they give?

Comment: This will depend on which Pokemon, and what you're trying to do with it, I'm afraid.  Can you restrict it to a specific Pokemon?

Comment: I would prefer restrict it to nature vs nature. Otherwise this question will be too specific.

Comment: Sorry, your title had me confused.  If you're looking for a Nature list, that we can definitely help with.

Comment: Yup this is something I'm pretty sure that all players will search after some time :)

Comment: My bad it didn't suggest me too look at this question thx @StrixVaria